# How to allocate memory for a char * when you don't know its size beforehand

Tags: c

i have this code :

```c
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);

    if (str == null)
        return (-1);
    if (av[0] != null) {
        strcpy(str, av[0]);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

i often hear that when i do malloc of sizeof 1024 it's ugly or not a good way to allocate memory, but from what i've learned from my researchs 512 or 1024 for examples are optimized for the processor to do its calculation, so what should i do when i don't know the size of the string i need to handle ?
ps: i know in the situation above i could do a strlen of av[0] it's just an illustration of my question.

Comment: I think you are looking for [a vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which has amortized `O(1)` performance when the [sequence of added capacities is grows geometrically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost). The answer with `realloc` is like this.

Comment: @Neil Note that here C is used, so `std::vector` is not an option.

Comment: I mean, the equivalent. Java's `ArrayList` is another example. With C you have to [programme your own](https://github.com/neil-edelman/array).

Comment: Here i'm trying to allocate memory for a string of character i'm not trying to make my own std::vector if i wanted to i would've made a linked list or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a 2 possibles approaches for this problem:

- you can compute the required size in an initial phase, then allocate the memory and finally use the array.
- you can keep track of the currently allocated size and reallocate the array as more space is needed along the way. You can call `realloc()` for that this function is somewhat tricky to use correctly.

Here is a modified version of your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    if (av[0] != NULL) {
        size_t n = strlen(av[0]) + 1;  // compute required size
        char *str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * n);
        if (str == NULL)
            return 1;
        memcpy(str, av[0], n);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        free(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `realloc()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    size_t size = 1024;
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * size);
    if (str == NULL)
        return 1;

    if (av[0] != NULL) {
        size_t n = strlen(av[0]) + 1;  // compute required size
        if (n > size) {
            char *newstr = realloc(str, n);
            if (!newstr) {
                free(str);
                return 1;
            }
            str = newstr;
            size = n;
        }
        memcpy(str, av[0], n);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        free(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But for this simple case, allocation is not required, `char *str = av[0];` would suffice. Yet if you need to allocate a copy of a C string, there is a simpler solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    if (av[0] != NULL) {
        char *str = strdup(av[0]);
        if (str == NULL)
            return 1;
        printf("%s\n", str);
        free(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler, `char *str = av[0];` no need to copy it.

Comment: @Neil: of course! but the whole purpose of the discussion is string allocation.

Comment: Of course, this is a good overview. I would add, sometimes you don't know how much is in the buffer. You could guess _a priori_, read that amount (1024), and when you see that that's not enough, `realloc` an exponentially bigger buffer and keep reading without _a posteriori_ `strlen`, _eg_ `getline`.